# "Undefined" json property

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase Cloud Functions, and I only use it to send notifications, so I wanted to make a class to simplify the creation of these notifications (json-like objects), but when accessing a property of that json-like object, it returns undefined.

The class is as follows:

```
class Notification 
{
    title: string
    body: string

    constructor(t: string, b: string)
    {
        this.title = t
        this.body = b
    }

    Message = 
    {
        "notification":
        {
            "title": this.title,
            "body": this.body
        }
    }
}
```

When accessing the title variable directly, it returns the correct value, example:

```
let newNotification = new Notification("TITLE", "BODY")
console.log(newNotification.title) // logs -> TITLE
```

But when accessing the message title, returns undefined:

```
console.log(newNotification.Message.notification.title) // logs -> undefined
```

The current code is the following:

```
let newNotification = new Notification ("Title test", "Body test")
console.log(newNotification.title) // logs -> Title test
console.log(newNotification.Message.notification.title) // logs -> undefined
admin.messaging ().sendToTopic (topic, newNotification.Message)
.then (topicNotificationMessage =>
{
    console.log("Notification OK")
    response.send("Notification OK")
})
.catch (notificationError =>
{
    console.log (notificationError)
    response.send("Notification Error" + notificationError)
})
```

The Firebase console logs this:

> Notification ErrorError: Messaging payload contains an invalid value for the "notification.title" property. Values must be strings.

Full error:

```
{ Error: Messaging payload contains an invalid value for the "notification.title" property. Values must be strings.
    at FirebaseMessagingError.Error (native)
    at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:42:28)
    at FirebaseMessagingError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:88:28)
    at new FirebaseMessagingError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:253:16)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:615:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:612:32
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Messaging.validateMessagingPayload (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:605:21)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:442:37
  errorInfo: 
   { code: 'messaging/invalid-payload',
     message: 'Messaging payload contains an invalid value for the "notification.title" property. Values must be strings.' },
  codePrefix: 'messaging' }
```

I honestly don't know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have a scope issue with the level that your 'notification' method is calling from. It does not see the value of what your expecting this.title to be. I'm assuming as well that if you were to drop the this.title it would also give you a null value for this.body. The notification method has it's own title, and body var and they are not set. I'm not sure what the solution is as it has been years since I've done this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, @Elijah.

I changed it like this, and now it works:

```
class Notification 
{
    constructor(t: string, b: string)
    {
        this.Message.notification.title = t
        this.Message.notification.body = b
    }

    Message = 
    {
        "notification":
        {
            "title": "",
            "body": ""
        }
    }
}
```